# Add WooCommerce cart link + total as last menu item in wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, nav

I am trying to add a custom WooCommerce cart link with contents count and total cost as the last option in a menu.

**This is my code that I am currently using:**

```php
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_header-menu_items','custom_minicart_in_main_menu', 10, 2);
function custom_minicart_in_main_menu( $menu, $args) {

    $minicart_link = '<a class="custom-minicart" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( "View Your Cart" ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf ( _n( "%d item", "%d items", WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>';

    return $menu . $minicart_link;

}
```

**Problem is, the only thing that is shown as a result is:**

```
">cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
```

**The result should be:**

```
Cart (#number of items) - $total cost of all products (subtotal using wc_price)
```

**So, like this:**

```
Cart (4) - $78.50
```

---

How can I adjust my code so that I get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) - Displays a navigation menu - contains `wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items` filter hook.

```php
/**
 * Filters the HTML list content for a specific navigation menu.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @see wp_nav_menu()
 *
 * @param string   $items The HTML list content for the menu items.
 * @param stdClass $args  An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 */
$items = apply_filters( "wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items", $items, $args );
```

---

So to answer your question, use:

```php
function custom_minicart_in_main_menu( $items, $args ) {
    // Get cart url
    $link_url = wc_get_cart_url();
    
    // Text
    $link_text = sprintf( __( 'Cart (%d) - %s', 'woocommerce' ), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count, WC()->cart->get_total() );
    
    // Link
    $minicart_link = '<a class="custom-minicart" href="' . $link_url . '">' . $link_text . '</a>';

    return $items . $minicart_link;

}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_header-menu_items', 'custom_minicart_in_main_menu', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Ah, that's just awesome. Thanks. Now I just gotta figure out how to incorporate the WC official documentation for cart fragments. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this approach.
Is there any way to do this and still have page caching active? I struggle that the cart (1) XX,YY text refers to an old amount if the user navigates elsewhere. Not talking about WC pages here (where caching is disabled), but normal pages/posts.