# Subtracting cart subtotal to cart total error issue In WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, numeric

Based on the answer code from my previous question [Add WooCommerce cart link + total as last menu item in wp_nav_menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65651390/add-woocommerce-cart-link-total-as-last-menu-item-in-wp-nav-menu), I am now trying to add shipping as an additional argument to the link.

I needed an if statement, making sure the cart is not empty. I then thought that it would be easiest to just to a simple calculation and that way, get the shipping total (order total minus subtotal).

Problem is; I get a two notices saying Warning: `A non-numeric value encountered`. The warning refers to this line:

```
$shipping_total = wc_price($order_total - $order_subtotal);
```

**This is the code:**

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_header-menu_items', 'minicart_link_with_product_count_subtotal_and_shipping', 10, 2 );
function minicart_link_with_product_count_subtotal_and_shipping( $items, $args ) {

    $order_total = wc_price(WC()->cart->get_total());

    $order_subtotal = wc_price(WC()->cart->get_subtotal());

    $shipping_total = wc_price($order_total - $order_subtotal);

    // cart url
    $link_url = wc_get_cart_url();   

    // icon, product count, subtotal and shipping (based on if statement)
    if (WC()->cart->is_empty()){

        $link_text = sprintf( __( '<i class="shopping-cart"></i> (0)', 'woocommerce' ));

    } else {

        $link_text = sprintf( __( '<i class="shopping-cart"></i> %d - %s (%s)', 'woocommerce' ), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count, wc_price(WC()->cart->get_subtotal()), $shipping_total);

    }

    // link
    $minicart_link = '<a title="View my cart" class="wfminicart" href="' . $link_url . '">' . $link_text . '</a>';

    // return the link as last menu item
    return $items . $minicart_link;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `wc_price()` formatting function from the 2 first variables and to replace `WC()->cart->get_total()` with `WC()->cart->total` to avoid This issue.

So your code is going to be:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_header-menu_items', 'minicart_link_with_product_count_subtotal_and_shipping', 10, 2 );
function minicart_link_with_product_count_subtotal_and_shipping( $items, $args ) {
    $order_total    = WC()->cart->total; // <= Here non formatted total

    $order_subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

    $shipping_total = wc_price($order_total - $order_subtotal);

    // cart url
    $link_url = wc_get_cart_url();   

    // icon, product count, subtotal and shipping (based on if statement)
    if (WC()->cart->is_empty()){

        $link_text = sprintf( __( '<i class="shopping-cart"></i> (0)', 'woocommerce' ));

    } else {

        $link_text = sprintf( __( '<i class="shopping-cart"></i> %d - %s (%s)', 'woocommerce' ), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count, wc_price(WC()->cart->get_subtotal()), $shipping_total);

    }

    // link
    $minicart_link = '<a title="View my cart" class="wfminicart" href="' . $link_url . '">' . $link_text . '</a>';

    // return the link as last menu item
    return $items . $minicart_link;
}
```

It should work without errors.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, yes, that fixed one of the notices, but one remains.

Comment: There were two notices and they were both the same. `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered`. With your code, one is removed and one remains. It still refers to the same line: `$shipping_total = wc_price($order_total - $order_subtotal);`

Comment: It does work when adding `return` and changing it into `return $items . $minicart_link;` Thanks!

Comment: @HaroldAldersen Oups! My fault… I forgot to replace that in my last edit,